# Image added to canvas is bigger than the canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

```
       <Grid Name="PlotGrid" Margin="50,50,50,50">
             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="500" />
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Canvas Name="canvas" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  />
               <Border Name="firstborder"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="0"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1">
            </Border>
            <Border Name="secondborder"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="0"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1">
            </Border>
                <Border Name="thirdborder"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="1"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1">
            </Border>
            <Border Name="fourthborder"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="1"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1">
            </Border>
        </Grid>
```

I am dynamically adding an image to the canvas above, which is inside a grid cell:

```
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        // Insert code to read the stream here.
                        image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri( openFileDialog.FileName));
                        canvas.Children.Add(image1);
                    }
                }
            }
```

My expectation is that the imported image will remain inside the canvas and inside the grid cell that contains the canvas. But it occupies a huge space well beyond the grid cell. How can I keep the imported image within the confines of the grid cell?

Comment: The grid cells dimensions are fixed (ex: Grid.Row Height=x Grid.Column Width=Y) ?

Comment: Maybe post the entire Xaml of your page to better understand

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the image size, otherwise it will be full size

```
image1.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
image1.StretchDirection = StretchDirection.Both;
image1.BeginInit();
image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri( openFileDialog.FileName));
image1.Width = canvas.ActualWidth;
image1.Height = canvas.ActualHeight;
image1.EndInit();
```

You may also need to add code to handle resizing of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might work:

```
...
image1.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
image1.StretchDirection = StretchDirection.Both;

image1.BeginInit();
image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri( openFileDialog.FileName));
image1.EndInit();

canvas.Children.Add(image1);
```

Comment: @user2192101: I've updated my answer to put it in context, including `BeginInt()` and `EndInit()` calls. Does this help?